# Textarea auto height, the same height maintained while refreshing on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I defined Textarea auto height.
If data keyed on textarea auto height will be working fine. and I stored localstorage in browser. when refreshing the page height will changed to the normal height and text will be hidden.
I need to the same height when refreshing the page. Please guide me. Thanks in advance. sorry for poor english.

```js
  function saveEdits1() {
    var editElem = document.getElementById("post_title");
    var userVersion1 = editElem.value;
    sessionStorage.userEdits1 = userVersion1;
  }
  
  function checkEdits() {
    if( sessionStorage.userEdits1!=null){
    document.getElementById("post_title").value = sessionStorage.userEdits1;
    }
}
     function textAreaAdjust(txt) {
            txt.style.height = "10px";
            txt.style.height = (25+txt.scrollHeight)+"px";
        }
```

```html
<body onload="checkEdits()">  
           <div class="container"> 
                <div class="cont_group1"> 
                  <div class="form-group">  
                       <textarea cols="33" onkeydown="textAreaAdjust(this)" style="overflow:hidden"  name="post_title" id="post_title" onblur="saveEdits1()" class="form-control"></textarea>
                  </div>  
                </div>
             </div>
             </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

make a fake event to trigger key event in your textarea.

```js
        function saveEdits1() {
          var editElem = document.getElementById("post_title");
          var userVersion1 = editElem.value;
          sessionStorage.userEdits1 = userVersion1;
        }

        function checkEdits() {
          if (sessionStorage.userEdits1 != null) {
      document.getElementById("post_title").value = sessionStorage.userEdits1;            
            
            var ev = new Event("keypress", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
            var el = document.getElementById("post_title");
                el.addEventListener("keypress",textAreaAdjust(el));
                el.dispatchEvent(ev)
          }
        }
        function textAreaAdjust(txt) {
          txt.style.height = "10px";
          txt.style.height = (25 + txt.scrollHeight) + "px";
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Starfleet</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    
    
</head>
<body onload="checkEdits()">
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="cont_group1"> 
      <div class="form-group">  
        <textarea cols="33" onkeydown="textAreaAdjust(this)" style="overflow:hidden"  name="post_title" id="post_title" onblur="saveEdits1()" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad to help my friend :-)